# Need guides in understanding the C++ codes

Tags: c++, sfml

can someone explain me on what does these codes did? this is only part of the code...

```
 // Create the window of the application
  sf::RenderWindow myWindow(sf::VideoMode(myWorldWidth, myWorldHeight, 32),    "Battleship!");
  myWindow.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

  bool showHardwareMouse;
  bool started;
  bool drag;
  float dragOffsetX, dragOffsetY;
  bool LeftMouseButtonDown = false;
  bool reset = true;


  //----- Main Loop Start here -----
  while (myWindow.isOpen())
  {
    if (reset)
    {
      // Reset
      showHardwareMouse = true;
      drag = false;
      dragOffsetX = dragOffsetY = 0.0f;
      started = true;
      reset = false;
    }
```

the program is actually based on SFML library, what does dragOffsetX = dragOffsetY = 0.0f; means?

and this is how actually the program work like...
http://i1146.photobucket.com/albums/o530/HTHVampire/C%20plus%20plus/Capture2_zps1fe188cd.jpg

I will post the full codes of it if you guys can't get it. Thanks!

Comment: Not a whole lot, resets some variables

Comment: ... and remember: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) does not only help you understand your own problem but it does help others understand it, too.

Comment: It does **1** not compile, because its not complete, and **2** not initialize some of the variables, wich is often considered bad style, and **3** not much apart of the assignments you see in the code. If understanding the assignments is your problem, it would help reading a introductory book to C++ and programming in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dragOffsetX = dragOffsetY = 0.0f;
```

is the same as

```
dragOffsetX = (dragOffsetY = 0.0f);
```

where an assignment `a = b` has the "value" b. So the above line is the same as:

```
dragOffsetX = 0.0f;
dragOffsetY = 0.0f;
```

The rest of the code consists mainly of declarations and initializations and should be obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what does this code do actually?

Comment: Assigns zero to two floating point variables. You perhaps need to spend some time learning simple C++ concepts before you try to understand more complicated code?

Comment: ya, i did understand, just don't get it what does this code will actually bring any impacts to the program...

Comment: If those variables are used elsewhere, then yes, it'll have an effect. That depends on how they're used though. I imagine it'll reset how far the program thinks the user has dragged the mouse.